# Allocating physical memory for Unsigned Integer in Visual Basic .NET?

Tags: vb.net

For example,

For integer, we allocate some memory and get its address:

```
Dim MyPointer As IntPtr =   Marshal.AllocHGlobal(4)

Marshal.WriteInt32(MyPointer, 255)
```

For String,

```
Dim MyStrPointer As IntPtr = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAuto("Hello World")
```

Similary, I want to allocate memory for an Unsigned Integer (UInt32)

Answer (score 0):

Unsigned integers like other .Net numeric types are structures and as such can be marshaled using Marshal.StructureToPtr and Marshal.PtrToStructure.

```
Dim origUI32 As UInt32 = UInt32.MaxValue
Dim MyPointer As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(origUI32))
Marshal.StructureToPtr(origUI32, MyPointer, True)

Dim retrievedUI32 As UInt32 = DirectCast(Marshal.PtrToStructure(MyPointer, GetType(UInt32)), UInt32)
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(MyPointer)
Debug.Assert(retrievedUI32 = origUI32)
```